# Updating Parent scope from child doesnot update ngrepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Im having problem communicating child controller with parent controller,
i hv a function that push data to parent array which is included in ngrepeat.

after pushing the parent array is appended correctly, and its length is shown correctly in parent controller, yet the ngrepeat doesnot refresh.

```
<div ng-controller="parentCtrl">
This works {{shared.arr.length}} <br/>
This works Too{{shared.arr|json}} <br/>

<div ng-repeat="a in shared.arr">
{{a}} This dont, it only show old data.
</div>

<section ng-contoller="childCtrl">
<button ng-click="test()">Test</button>
</section>
</div>
angular.module('testApp')
  .controller('parentCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.shared = {arr:[1,2]};
});
  .controller('childCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.test = function(){$scope.shared.arr.push(4);}
});
```

Comment: $scope.test = function(){$scope.$parent.shared.arr.push(4);} use it like this to directly access and manipulate parent scope object

Comment: @SerhatCan no need of `$parent` here,,as parent has created a object structure do follow prototypal inheritance..the fix would be from changing `ng-contoller` to `ng-controller`

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.module('testApp', [])
  .controller('parentCtrl', ['$scope', parentCtrl])
  .controller('childCtrl', ['$scope', childCtrl]);

function parentCtrl ($scope) {
  $scope.shared = {
    arr: [1, 2]
  };
}
function childCtrl ($scope) {
  $scope.test = function (arr) {
    arr.push(4);
  }
}

<div ng-controller="childCtrl">
    <button ng-click="test(shared.arr)">Test</button>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kikill/zhzb3pxh/

try this code.

there were 2 mistakes: 
1) ng-controller="childCtrl", not ng-contoller="childCtrl"
2) you passed into 'test' function parent's variable. It can make a lot of errors that no so clear in this example, but it can be.
Use 'controller as' syntax. You can read about this [here](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/).

Answer (score 0):

Since this code is working fine in my case, I will assume that in your code also you have done the mistake of writing controller as contoller in`<ng-contoller="childCtrl">` , which is a very silly mistake :)